# Make a httplib connection persistent, everwhere

Tags: python, python-2.7, keep-alive, httplib

I am using the httplib library (python 2.7), and as you are probably aware, it needs to make a TCP handshake every time a new connection is made, and this can take a few seconds, which I have been trying to negate for some considerable time . I *do* use a `Keep-Alive` header with my requests, but the REST server I am consuming has a very short timeout (<30 seconds), so I need to either refresh the current connection, or make a new one, hence a new wait (out of the question in this case).

In the past, as a way around this I have used (admittedly bizzare), something like the following:

```
#script 1
import zmq

#Set PUSH socket
context = zmq.Context()
ventilator_send = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
ventilator_send.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")

def SOCKET_SENDS(INFO):

        try:
            ventilator_send.send(INFO,zmq.NOBLOCK)
        except Exception, e:
            print "Socket failure - check client", e

#send content 
msg     = json.dumps({'MKT':{'A':123,'B':456}})
SOCKET_SENDS(msg)
```

And then I send the requests to the following:

```
#script 2
context = zmq.Context()
work_receiver = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
work_receiver.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(work_receiver, zmq.POLLIN)

#make initial handshake
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('site')

while True:
        socks = dict(poller.poll(25000))
        if socks:
                if socks.get(work_receiver) == zmq.POLLIN:
                        RESP = json.loads(work_receiver.recv(zmq.NOBLOCK))

                        if  RESP.has_key('MKT'):
                                conn.request(GET, POST, PUT..., params, {'Connection' :'Keep-Alive'})
                                write_pickle(conn.getresponse())

                        if  RESP.has_key('LMT'):
                                conn.request(GET, POST, PUT..., params, {'Connection' :'Keep-Alive'})
                                write_pickle(conn.getresponse())

                        if  RESP.has_key('TPP'):
                                conn.request(GET, POST, PUT..., params, {'Connection' :'Keep-Alive'})
                                write_pickle(conn.getresponse())
        ...


        else:
                conn.request(GET, POST, PUT..., params, {'Connection' :'Keep-Alive'})
                consume_scrap_response = conn.getresponse())
```

So, all this to keep a HTTP connection persistent, this is overkill right? (and to say it's prone to error is an understatement) Does anyone have a (simple?) method at hand where I could just keep `conn` alive and call it anywhere, from other threads/scripts?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do all of your scripts make enough requests to keep the connection perpetually open? One possible solution would be to use nginx as a forward proxy to your target website to persist connections with keep-alive and have a second script perpetually request a non-existent resource to prevent the connection from closing if the initial handshake really takes that much time.

Comment: @Blender This is what is actually happening here: if we have not polled script 2 in 25 seconds it makes a dummy request (the `else` statement) to keep `conn` alive. But rather than do any work in script 2 (because there is rather a lot of it in reality), it would be much easier if I could just take the connection object `conn` from the ventilator and use it in other threads. In this way I always have an open connection.

Comment: @Blender As a side note, I can send a connection object through a function into another script, so in some sense, it is theoretically possible. So i call `def foo(conn): conn request` with `foo(conn)` etc.

Comment: By "threads", do you mean threads or processes? Because you can easily share connections between threads, but sharing a socket between processes is usually not possible and it's much easier to just make a proxy.

Comment: @Blender Yes sorry, they are separate processes, many of them. So you think I should take a different approach? Not a problem, it's beginning to annoy me anyhow. Thanks for input.